# how to set min-width, max-width, min-height, max-height for canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = 1920;
        canvas.height = 1080;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

I am uploading this image, but I want to make sure that if the pixels of the uploading image is less than 480p, it will draw a 480p image on canvas before upload and if the pixels of the uploading image is greater than 1080p, it will draw a 1080p image on canvas before upload.

**So basically my question is, is there any way to set min-height, max-height, min-width, and max-width on canvas or any other alternative through which I can change the resolution of the image before uploading.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do the below, please note a very quick answer you may want to improve the code:

```
 function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("src", img);

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(image.height == 1080){
            canvas.width = 1920;
            canvas.height = 1080;
        }
        if(image.height == 480){
            canvas.width = 640;
            canvas.height = 480;
        }
    },0)

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Comment: Use `image.addEventListener("onload", () => { /*instead of setTimeout*/ });` also, you should draw within the onload, not before or after the event.

Comment: yes I figured that out already, Thanks for the solution, it worked for me.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it solved your issue!